# How do I filter a c# datatable using a rowfilter with multiple asterisks?

Tags: c#, string, datatable, filtering

I've got a data table that uses row filters. Here's an example of the types of matches I need. I only use asterisks.

String I'm checking: "Hello how are you"

Filter: "*" - Match
Filter: "Hello*" - Match
Filter: "Hello" - No Match
Filter: "*how*" - Match
Filter: "Hello*you" - Match
Filter: "H*l*w*r*u" - Match

When I try to use more than 2 asterisks, I get an exception that says "the string pattern is invalid".

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Row filter can not use * in the middle of the string. I would use something like this instead.
Usage:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name").Like("H*l*w*r*u"));
```

Like function:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Like(this string s, string pattern, RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try % instead for wildcard filter:

```
System.Data.DataRow[] y = x.Select("Col2 LIKE 'smith[%]%'");
System.Data.DataRow[] y = x.Select("Col2 = 'smith%'");
```